# Growth of Laplacian eigenvalues on a compact domain?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, dg.differential-geometry, differential-operators, laplacian

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and let $\Delta$ be the (scalar) Laplace-Beltrami operator on $\mathcal{M}$.  Then $\Delta$ has a discrete spectrum and if we order its **distinct** eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ by magnitude then some very simple examples suggest that the magnitude of $\lambda_i$ might be roughly quadratic in $i$.  For instance, on the circle $S^1$ eigenfunctions have the form $\cos(nx)$ or $\sin(nx)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$; hitting these functions with $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}$ yields $n^2\cos(nx)$ and $n^2\sin(nx)$, respectively.  Similar analysis can be done for the geometrically flat torus $T^2$.  On the 2-sphere, we have $\lambda_i=i(i+1)$.  This rough idea of "differentiating twice leads to a square" makes me suspect that a similar relationship might hold for other domains -- what can be said in general?  I'm particularly interested in smooth surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

*Update*: [Weyl's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum#Weyl.27s_formula) provides some valuable information about the Laplace spectrum, but does not determine the asymptotic growth of $\lambda_i$.  For instance, suppose we have a manifold such that $N(R) \approx R$, i.e., the number of eigenvalues with value no greater than $R$ is roughly equal to $R$ itself.  Letting $n_i$ be the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$, this relationship holds for, say, $\lambda_i = i(i+1)$ and $n_i = 2i+1$ (which is the situation on the sphere), since

$$ N(\lambda_i) = \sum_{j=0}^i n_j = \sum_{j=0}^i 2i+1 = i^2 + 2i + 1 \approx i(i+1) = \lambda_i. $$

But it also holds for $\lambda_i = i$ and $n_i = 1$ since then

$$ N(\lambda_i) = \sum_{j=0}^i n_j = \sum_{j=0}^i 1 = i + 1 \approx i = \lambda_i. $$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Weyl's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum#Weyl.27s_formula):

$$N(R)=\frac{1}{(4{\cdot}\pi)^{d/2}{\cdot}\Gamma\left(\frac d2+1\right)}{\cdot}V{\cdot}R^{d/2}+o(R^{d/2}).$$
where $d$ --- dimension, $V$ --- volume, $N(R)$ --- number of eigenvalues $\le R$.
It works for any compact Riemannian manifold.

Comment: Not sure I understand the connection (also: the link is broken; had to Google it).

I guess I should also mention that I'm not interested with surfaces with boundary (or Dirichlet boundary conditions).

Comment: Great -- thanks for the clarification.  (Also, looks like it should be $o(R^{(d-1)/2})$.)

Comment: I must be interpreting one of your constants incorrectly -- for the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the distinct eigenvalues are $\lambda_i = i(i+1)$ appearing with multiplicity $2i+1$.  So then the number of eigenvalues with value no greater than $\lambda_i$ is $\sum_{j=0}^i 2j + 1 = i^2 + 2i + 1$.  In other words, we have $R(i) = i^2 + i$ and $N(R(i)) = i^2 + 2i + 1$, hence $N(R) \approx R$.  But for $d=2$ and $V=4\pi$, Weyl's formula says $N(R) \approx R/4\pi$.  Where does the factor $1/4\pi$ come from?

Comment: The constant above is incorrect. For the correct formula and some modern developments see http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/mueller/papers/weyllaw.pdf

Comment: Very interesting -- thanks!  Unfortunately I don't think relationships like Weyl's formula answer my original question.  For instance, suppose (for the sake of argument) that $N(R) \approx R$.  Then the growth of eigenvalues is still ambiguous.  For instance, $\lambda_i$ could be quadratic in $i$ and have multiplicity linear in $i$, but alternatively $\lambda_i$ could be *linear* in $i$ and have *constant* multiplicity.  Either scenario satisfies $N(R) \approx R$.

Comment: @GH, hope it is correct now.

Comment: fuzzytron: Both scenarios you propose happen. Symmetric examples are highly degenerate. Break the symmetry and you lose degeneracy ... Of course a small perturbation will still have "almost high multiplicities".

Comment: @fuzzytyron: In general it is a very difficult question how eigenvalues are distributed, what are their multiplicities, how many are there in short intervals etc. For example, for the modular surface (upper half-plane modulo $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$) it is conjectured that each eigenvalue has multiplicity one, but we only have very weak results in that direction.

Comment: @GH: Thanks -- yeah, I'm not terribly surprised to hear that.  Are there known examples of 2-manifolds where the multiplicities are anything other than linear (apart from the conjecture you mention)?  Really I'm interested in surfaces that represent "everyday objects," e.g., the boundaries of (reasonably smooth) objects you might have sitting around your house.  [I wish there were a concise term for such surfaces -- something like smooth, compact, connected, orientable 2-manifolds with small genus.]

Comment: @fuzzytron: For the torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ the multiplicities are very small (far from linear), but I am sure you know this. I am no expert in these matters, but I would think that on a generic surface (e.g. with no symmetry, variable curvature etc.) all multiplicities are equal to one.